# Enabling the hstore extension in Amazon RDS from Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-rds

I have a Rails 4 application that uses ActiveRecord to interact with a PostgreSQL 9.3 database. The application makes use of the `hstore` extension in PostgreSQL for storing key-value pairs in a single database field. Accordingly, Rails automatically detects what I did with that migration and creates the following line in your schema.rb file

```
enable_extension "hstore"
```

In the development and test environments, that works great, as I am deploying to stand-alone PostgreSQL instances. However in production, I am deploying to a PostgreSQL instance in Amazon RDS, where the extension must be installed by a member of the `rds_superuser` group. I'd rather not put my application user in that role.

**Is there a way to make the execution of that code dependent on the environment? For example, run the code in development in test, but not on deploys to production?**

I've tried creating a migration that's conditional, but it doesn't eliminate the line above when the schema is generated. Example:

```
class ModifyHstoreSetup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    if %w(staging, production).include?(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development")
      enable_extension "plpgsql"
      enable_extension "hstore"
    end
  end
  def self.down
    if %w(staging, production).include?(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development")
      disable_extension "plpgsql"
      disable_extension "hstore"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but a tweak to some of the code above. Can I recommend `Rails.env.production?` instead of the string-based checking?

Answer (score 0):

Just make your user member of rds_superuser group. Then your migration will succeed.

Comment: yes, on production... with microservice... and your product has user private information