# must be owner of extension plpgsql error when executing pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

i was trying to restore database on amazon rds.. i am getting error message like:

```
ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql CREATE EXTENSION
ERROR:  must be owner of extension dblink  CREATE EXTENSION
ERROR:  must be owner of extension pgcrypto
```

Any idea how to solve this issue ?.

Comment: do you try create the extension using pgadmin first?

Comment: no . i just tried to restore the data base.

Comment: `rds_super` isn't a real superuser, which imposes a variety of issues. You can probably safely ignore these errors. Probably.

Comment: I mean create the extension db_link before run the restore database.

Comment: Do you get your data restored?

Comment: I'm having this issue to when restoring.

Comment: suppose user **A** is the current owner of the database/schema and you are currently using user **B** which triggered that error, maybe this can be solved by granting **B** with all privileges of **A**. e.g. `GRANT user_a TO user_b`

Answer (score 1):

I believe both of those extensions are supported by RDS.
See:

```
$SHOW rds.extensions;
```

Retrieved from [this link](https://gist.github.com/joshuaflanagan/7495006)

As for enabling the syntax should be along the lines of

```
#enable_extension "dblink";
```

As Craig Ringer mentioned rds_super isn't a real superuser. So, you can't create the extensions. However, you should be able to enable them.

As in  [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986262/enabling-the-hstore-extension-in-amazon-rds-from-rails-4)

So, you can ignore the errors, but need to manually enable whatever extensions you need. Also I think pl/pgsql may be already there. Try

```
$\dx
```